# file_get_contents('php://input') returning empty string with a PATCH request

Tags: php, rest, nginx, patch

My environment is PHP 5.5.9, Nginx 1.4.6-1ubuntu3.2, localhost.

I'm trying to get data from PATCH method, but that just return an empty string...
With POST method that's work fine, this is a piece of my script :

```
case 'POST':
case 'PATCH':
     $this->data = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

$this->data is empty when PATCH method is used and complete when POST, i use the POSTMAN chrome extension and i push RAW data (not multipart/form-data)

I think Nginx was in fault...but nothing into the log file...

Any help will be much appreciated !

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into a similar issue trying to access `php://input` for a PUT request. The issue was simply that I had already accessed it once previously (in a logging function that ran prior to the code in question).

POST acts differently than the other methods, which explains the discrepancy:

> Note: Prior to PHP 5.6, a stream opened with php://input could only be read once; the stream did not support seek operations. However, depending on the SAPI implementation, it may be possible to open another php://input stream and restart reading. This is only possible if the request body data has been saved. Typically, this is the case for POST requests, but not other request methods, such as PUT or PROPFIND.

source: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

The solution was simple: Store the value of `php://input` from the initial grab to a PHP variable, and don't try to run `file_get_contents("php://input")` more than once for a non-POST request.

Comment: Many thanks for your advice, it helped me to solve my problem. I'd like to add, that you have not only to read it once, but it seems that you have to start to read the stream as the first thing in your script. First I have read this after reading the HTTP header and it worked for POST request, but not for PATCH. After moving the
 `$requestJSONBody = file_get_contents('php://input');` before reading HTTP header it started to work for PATCH too.