# how can i acces the JSON data of POST request sent through ajax to a php file and store them in an array variable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, frontend

I send json data through ajax to a php file called in case 'receive.php'.

`user_name` , `user_id`, etc. are defined on top of my script page you may change by anything else.

Here is my js code :

```
const data = {
  name: user_name,
  id: user_id,
  score: success,
  time: endTime

};

const jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);

const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "receive.php", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.send(jsonString);
```

This is my php file

```
<?php


  header('Content-Type' , 'application/json');
  $requestPayload = file_get_contents('php://input');
  $json = json_decode($requestPayload , true);



  $not = 'gsvcgdsqc';

  //This gives NULL
  var_dump($json);

  echo $not;


?>
```

in the browser (network), i can see sent data :

[image]

But when i try to store it in a variable and display it, it gives null :

[image]

So how can I access and store those data in a variable so I can use them after for other actions?

Comment: So likely the json is not right, add `if (json_last_error() > 0 ){ echo json_last_error_msg(); }` after the `json_decode()`

Comment: it says syntax error

Comment: do you have an idea how to debug that? please...

Comment: Can you do a `echo $requestPayload;` and show us that also please

Comment: it's blank , shows nothing

Comment: Possible? https://stackoverflow.com/q/19146984/2943403

Comment: Dude, you do not need file_get_contents, can you just grab the $_POST ? it is sent as post through your ajax request

Comment: i need to send json data

Comment: Also worth a read: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11937886/2943403 Do you have any earlier scripts accessing the stream? https://stackoverflow.com/a/34730583/2943403

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'receive.php',
    data: data
});
```

You can then get the data with `$_POST`, no need for json.

Comment: always empty array(0){}

Answer (score 0):

It's showing as `NULL` when you type the URL into the address bar of the browser.

That's a completely different (GET) request to the POST request you make with JavaScript.

The request body of the POST request (containing the JSON) doesn't exist on the GET request, so of course it is NULL.

---

If you want to see the response to the POST request you made, then look in the *Preview* tab instead of the *Headers* tab in the Network monitor.

If you want to **store** the data somewhere and then **read it back** on a subsequent request then you need to do that explicitly by writing code to do it.

Start by picking somewhere to store it (such as a session or a database).

Comment: so it's not possible to store them automatically? without typing manually?

Comment: No. Software only does what you program it to do.